# I have written a program to login into yahoomail. but its giving me an error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written a program to click on a link, enter the username and Password and then click on the Signin Button, but i'am not getting the output and its giving me an error.
The Program is as below

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class CssSelector3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='yui_3_12_0_1_1454585688215_223']/div/ul[1]/li[1]/a")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login-username")).sendKeys("tester@yahoo.com");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login-passwd")).sendKeys("tester1234");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login-signin")).click();
    }
}
```

The program executes only till the maximize window part and then it stops. Can anyone assist me on this.

Comment: Can you post your log?

Comment: did'nt get it..? log as in ??

Comment: What type error are you getting?

Comment: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='yui_3_12_0_1_1454585688215_223']/div/ul[1]/li[1]/a"}

Answer (score 1):

In your situation xpath of Sign In button is wrong. Yahoo generates everytime new id for its Sign In button. You can try following code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Sign In']"))
                .click();
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login-username"))
                .sendKeys("tester@yahoo.com");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login-passwd")).sendKeys("tester1234");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login-signin")).click();
    }
```

Comment: But how did u get this text "//*[text()='Sign In']" ?

Comment: In selenium to write xpath is an Art. We should write it irrespective of any browser and such that less maintenance required if UI changed. In selenium you can write Xpath in many ways. Just follow this [Xpath Documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) for different different new strategy.